# Wordpress Requesting and Loading Large Image instead of thumbnail which is increase page load time

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

On my blog's homepage though the thumbnails are of smaller size and resolution, but blog is calling the large images respectively, which is increasing the page load time. I have checked this in Pingdom and want to know if we can callout smaller images only to reduce the page load time.

Blog: ssbcrack.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use lazy load plugin for large imges

Answer (score 1):

Your image have the class "landscape thumbnail cp-small".

1. In the wordpress dashboard, open ssbcrack.com/wp-admin/options-media.php and check the "Thumbnail size". If doesn't work, next.
2. Will need to check your theme's PHP code to find the corresponding thumb size for landscape and cp-small. If you can't do so, hire someone.

Goodluck.

Comment: Hi, so I could see small, medium and large image file size, what to do to decrease the load size on homepage, I am not sure why it is calling large image when it is showing thumbnails on the homepage.

Comment: @user3137356 Please provide the piece of PHP code that print out the thumbnail on homepage. Thanks.

Comment: Where can I find the same, I am under which theme file? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @user3137356 It should be home.php or front-page.php

Comment: Hi, as this is a customized theme developed by someone, I am not able to find the same. Is there any tool which could tell us which php file is getting used on hompage?

Comment: Try this: Open the style.css file to find the "Template: xxx" That xxx is the folder of the parent theme. In the xxx folder, you will find the home.php, index.php or front-page.php. 

If you still don't know what to do, maybe you could zip the folder and send it to me to check for you.